# How to use NXOpen.Vector3d

Tags: c#

NXOpen.Vector3d represents a three-dimensional vector.

but Vector3d constructor is with 3 parameters:
public Vector3d(
    double X,
    double Y,
    double Z
)

How to understand the X Y Z can represents  three-dimensional vector?

Comment: Have you consulted the documentation? It seems reasonable just based on the name that a vector with 3 dimensions would be represented by 3 components along the X, Y, and Z axes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two point and create a vector between it. Then the difference between this points coordinates is the vector.

point a = a1,a2,a3 coordinate of point a
point b = b1,b2,b3 coordinate of point b.

vector3D ba = new Vector3D(b1-a1, b2-a2, b3-a3);
and vice versa.

Check nxopen documentation for more info